# Basic JQuery replaceWith() won't work

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I want to do a basic replaceWith operation in JQuery and it won't work.

Here is the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function changeCAT(){
$('#avg_scores').replaceWith('<div>Replacement Success!</div>');
};
$('#btn').click(changeCAT);

</script>

</head>
<body>
<input id = "btn" type = "button" value = "Change Div">
<div id = "avg_scores"> Original Div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I press the button, nothing happens.  I want to replace something much more significant in the final product, but I can't get this simple operation to work means I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: You need to put your script in  a dom ready handler

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5ydft555/1/

Comment: I don't understand. I'm new to JQuery.  What is a DOM ready handler and why do I need it?

Comment: have look at [learn.jquery.com](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/) - [dom ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: When I put it in the dom ready handler it executes on the page load. I want it to execute when I click the button.

Comment: did you see the demo I posted above where it is working just fine

Comment: OK now it works.  I have never seen the bit of code jQuery(function($).  what is that? It wasn't in the book I have.  Bery frustrating.

Comment: that is the same as `$(document).ready()` read the above posted links

Comment: Yeah when I put it in the $document.ready() though it executed immediately on page load.  With the example it waits until I hit the button.

Comment: I more fundamentally just don't know why I need to wrap it in the doc ready.